# Iterate through a lot of Structs

Tags: matlab, loops, struct

my Problem is the following:

I have about 300 Struct files given.
They are set up like this:

DSC_0001 has about 250 other struct files in it:
->  like this: DSC_0001.marker_1
And this one has 10 Numbers in it.
Like that:
DSC_0001.marker_1.flow_angle = 90

and now I want to iterate through all the Struct files
Something like that:

```
for i = 1:300
    for j = 1:250
         flow_angle = DSC_**i**.marker_**j**
    end
end
```

Is there a way to do this?
I have the feeling that it could be really easy but I just can't find the solution...
I hope my question is clear enough...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible don't use eval.

It depends on how your data is stored, but one possiblity is that it is in a .mat file. In that case it can be loaded using

```
DSC_structs = load('My_DSC_struct_file.mat');
```

and then you can access the values like so:

```
for i = 1:300
    for j = 1:250
        flow_angle(i,j) = DSC_structs.(['DSC_' sprintf('%04d',i)]).(['marker_' sprintf('%d',j)]);
    end
end
```

[Why avoid the eval function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html#bs7kmd5)

Edit: You say that each struct is in a different file. That's a bit messier. I would probably do something like this to load them:

```
DSC_structs = cell(1,300);
for i = 1:300
    %Note: I'm guess at your file names here
    DSC_structs{i} = load(['DSC_' sprintf('%04d',i) '.mat'];
end
```

and then access the values as

```
DSC_structs{i}.(['DSC_' sprintf('%04d',i)]).(['marker_' sprintf('%d',j)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a use case for the dreaded `eval` function:

```
for i = 1:300
    for j = 1:250
         eval (['flow_angle = DSC_', sprintf('%04d',i), '.marker_', num2str(j)]);
    end
end
```

BUT **NB** there are 2 problems with my code above

1. You haven't told us where you want to store your angle, so my code doesn't :/ but you'd want something like this if you just want to store them in a matrix: `eval (['flow_angle(', num2str(i), ',', num2str(j), ') = DSC_', sprintf('%04d',i), '.marker_', num2str(j)])`
2. `eval` is a horrible way of doing things but you're forced to because someone saved your data in a horrible. Sort yourself out now for the future by re-saving your data in a smarter way! so something like:

.

```
for i = 1:300
     eval ( ['DSC(', num2str(i), ') = DSC_', sprintf('%04d',i)]);
end
%// then save DCS!
```

And now your can iterate through this matrix of structs rather than having a 300 structs polluting your workspace and forcing you to use `eval`

Comment: thanks a lot!! eval is working! I wanted to store them in a matrix flow_angle(i,j)... Why is eval that horrible? Is it very slow?

Comment: @Bant it's a big mission to work with and also to debug. Very hard to read and write code etc. I really suggest that you save your data in a better format so that you can avoid eval in the future

Comment: @Bant Also please read ioums answer, it's a better alternative

Comment: Well I have the data in two formats. The Mat-files and txt-files! Therefore I thought that the mat-files may be better to use. But in this case I may just switch to the txt files